# how to copy and paste with cursor in ubuntu commad line terminal except GUI

Tags: command-line

this is balaji v using ubuntu command line terminal only exclude GUI.command and ouput getting everything is fine,but one thing is cursor was used to copy and paste the some id's and disk partitions not supporttable.how to use this please provide is there any video links

Answer (score 3):

If you are asking about the console , aka the command line without a graphical interface, you can use the mouse to copy paste if you install `gpm` which stands for General Purpose Mouse

```
sudo apt install gpm
```

Here is a video of it in action in Virtualbox but it is the same on a console outside virtualbox

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Nk1p45VMVpM